# sql where subquery on id

Tags: sql

struggling to get my head round this.
i want to convert the following sql statement (converted from oracle to sql) to return all, not individual record.

```
select * 
from table_1 
where ID = @myid and MyMonth = (select max (MyMonth) from table2 where ID = @myid)
```

by as i said, i would like to return as a summary of everything not for the given value of @myid.

remove the where ID parts of this returns nothing.

thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * 
from table_1 t1
where t1.MyMonth = (select max (t2.MyMonth) from table2 t2 where t1.ID = t2.ID)
```

Comment: that is great! but it takes a lot of time, do you know why?

Comment: not sure if there is a better way to solve this... but it will likely help to have an index on MyMonth.